# Scatterplot of packed circles in d3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot, circle-pack

Is there a way to create a sparse scatterplot visualization where each "point" on the plot is a one-level [packed circle](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530)? I've been trying to do this with d3, but I don't know if it's possible to make multiple different pack layouts in the same svg... (or if that's even how I should approach it). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm hoping it would end up looking something like the following rough sketch:
 [image]

Comment: Is this really circle packing?  Or just a bunch of circles in parent circle place at coordinates?

Comment: I meant for the circles in my sketch to be packed within the parent circles..even if it doesn't look that way -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just threw this together.  It takes d3 flare data and will scatter-plot out the first level children and their children.

Data Structure:

```
var flareData = {
  "name": "root",
  "children": [{
    "name": "pointOne",
    "scatX": 10,
    "scatY": 20,
    "children": [{
      "name": "pointOneA",
      "children": [{
        "name": "A",
        "size": 40
      }, {
        "name": "B",
        "size": 50
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "pointOneB",
      "children": [{
        "name": "C",
        "size": 10
      }, {
        "name": "D",
        "size": 23
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "pointTwo",
...
```

Typical `d3` code to create plot and axes:

```
var
 WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 600,
  DIAMETER = 200;

var vis = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', WIDTH)
  .attr('height', HEIGHT);

var MARGINS = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 50
},
  xRange = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
    .domain([d3.min(flareData.children, function(d) {
      return d.scatX;
    }) - 10, d3.max(flareData.children, function(d) {
      return d.scatX;
    }) + 10]),
  yRange = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
    .domain([d3.min(flareData.children, function(d) {
      return d.scatY;
    }) - 10, d3.max(flareData.children, function(d) {
      return d.scatY;
    }) + 10]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xRange)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickSubdivide(true),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient('left')
    .tickSubdivide(true);

vis.append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

vis.append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
  .call(yAxis);
```

Let the abuse of the packed layout start:

```
// normal packed layout
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([DIAMETER - 4, DIAMETER - 4])
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  });

// classify each level
var node = vis.datum(flareData).selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {        
    // root level
    if (!d.parent) {
      return "node rootNode";
    // first level children, these are our scatter points
    } else if (d.children && !d.parent.parent) {
      return "node pointNode";
    // an intermediate circle
    } else if (d.children) {
      return "node innerNode";
    // last level packing
    } else {
      return "node innerNode packedNode";
    }
  });

// use calculated radius
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  });

// we don't care about root circle, move off page
node.filter(".rootNode")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + -100 + "," + -100 + ")");

// this is our scatter point
node.filter(".pointNode")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + xRange(d.scatX) + "," + yRange(d.scatY) + ")";
  });

// any circle in a scatter point
node.filter(".innerNode")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var iter = d;
    while(!iter.scatX){
      iter = iter.parent;
    }
    // diff from scatter point...
    var difX = iter.x - d.x,
        difY = iter.y - d.y;
    return "translate(" + (xRange(iter.scatX) + difX) + "," + (yRange(iter.scatY) + difY) + ")";
  })

// finally label our last level
node.filter(".packedNode")
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".3em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });
```

Example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/28eccafd4a9cb02bb33b).

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve:

http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for? I know my sketch was pretty rough, but I didn't mean for them to be just clumped and determined by force. I want to be able to create multiple packed circles within an svg and be able to position them on an x-y scatterplot.. do you know if there are examples of that?